# which tag to use if i want to select an option from dropdown as wel as i can insert my own option

Tags: html, jsp

which tag to use if i want to select an option from dropdown as wel as i can insert my own option.

so using jsp can i do it? i m able to fetch the complete list to serve as option but i want to insert my own option as wel.
what is the convenient technique using jsp?
i mean like the way we insert into text box. i have seen in some sites that they provide options to choose and in one of the option you can fill ur own value
plz help

Comment: What do you mean by inserting your own option? A user entry directly on the page?

Comment: i mean like the way we insert into text box.
i have seen in some sites that they provide options to choose and in one of the option you can fill ur own value

Comment: Doubleposted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019778/can-i-insert-my-own-option-in-select-tag

Answer (score 1):

Insert your own option? That is not possible with plain HTML.